# What is "Exec format error"?

Tags: webcam, macbook, macbook-pro, 20.10

I'm running Ubuntu Budgie 20.10 on a MacBook Pro 12.1 and while trying to get the built-in camera working (using [this](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki) and [this](https://victorleungtw.com/2020/04/24/install-ubuntu-macbook-pro.html)) I got this error message:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'facetimehd': Exec format error
```

The command that precipitated the message was `# modprobe facetimehd`

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

That happens when you want to use a module compiled for a different kernel version.

It could be because you forgot to reboot in between 2 alterations (you are still on the old kernel and the module is expecting the new kernel).

Another issue could be that you forgot to do a `make clean`.

---

With these 2 sources [#1](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie) and [#2](https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware):

```
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware
```

the commands to compile are ...

```
cd facetimehd-firmware/
make clean
make
sudo make install

cd ../bcwc_pcie/
make clean
make
sudo make install

sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
sudo vim /etc/modules
```

Comment: Many thanks! Everything went smoothly until `sudo modprobe facetimehd`:

`modprobe: FATAL: Module facetimehd not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic`