# New Kernel Broke My Driver

Tags: drivers, kernel

Got an `Exec format error` trying to fix a driver for my webcam (asked about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306267/what-is-exec-format-error)). Will I have to reinstall with every kernel update? Is `make clean` the way to handle this? Are some modules kernel-specific?

Answer (score 2):

If you install any kernel module without using `dkms`, you'll need to re-install it after each kernel upgrade.